# Android BottomAppBar is not hiding on scroll after changing orientation

Tags: android, layout, material-design, bottomnavigationview, bottombar

In my application I have an activity. By attaching the fragment to the activity I hide the `BottomAppBar`. So in my Fragment the `BottomAppBar` is not visible. When I change the orientation from portrait to landscape the `BottomAppBar` is visible after orientation change. So `onResume` I put this  `myBottomBar.performHide()` in my Fragment but this has no effect. The `BottomAppBar` is still visible. Furthermore in the layout file I set the flag `app:hideOnScroll="true"` to the `BottomAppBar` but this also don't work after an orientation change.

Comment: Not sure, but have you checked on the 'onConfigurationChanged()' method?

Comment: Yes, I tried to call the `myBottomBar.performHide()` in onConfiguration change but this also had no effect.

Comment: I guess you should post your `layout.xml` for `app:hideOnScroll="true"` behavior... the scrolling view should be inside a `NestedScrollView`. Because it uses a custom `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>` which is dependent on an instance of `NestedScrollView`. Also it would be great if you could post some of the code.